# Cannot configure existing React-Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm, reactive-programming, react-native-ios

I am new learner for the React-Native and trying to setup the project on Mac.

I'm able to create the fresh project but unable to do so with the existing project using WebStorm IDE. I am trying since a week.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run your application using `node node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runIOS\runIOS.js`. This is not the right way to start React Native application. You need using [React Native](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-react-native.html) run configuration for this.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/react-native.html#starting_with_existing_react_native_application for more info.